# Image permissions after uploading for resize

Tags: php, image, file, permissions, chmod

I am having a user's profile page in which user uploads his profile picture from file dialog..

when the file is moved to my local server's folder it gets permission as 0644 only..

but I want to resize this image before getting uploaded into server...

And for this I need permission as 0777 to edit it...

How should I do it..

here is my code for move and resize

```
  $upload_dir = './images';
  $tmp = $_FILES["img"]["tmp_name"];
  $names = $_FILES["img"]["name"];
  $res=$moveR=move_uploaded_file($tmp, "$upload_dir/$names");

  $a="./images/".$names;        
  list($width, $height) = getimagesize($a);
  $newwidth = "300"; 
  $newheight = "200";
  $thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
  $source = imagecreatefromjpeg($a);
  imagecopyresized($thumb, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);
  imagejpeg($thumb, $a, 100);
```

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run this on the files:

```
chmod ($filepath, 0777);
```

in your case probably:

```
chmod("$upload_dir/$names",0777);
```

Answer (score 0):

add  this code with your absolute path

```
 $file_path = $path.'/files/ChatRequestXML/'.$profile_id.'.jpg'; // change with your actual path
        chmod($file_path, 0777);
```

hope this will sure help you

Answer (score 0):

you need to add this line after move_uploaded_file function to set 777 permission for the uploaded file

```
<?php
   exec("chmod $upload_dir/$names 0777");
?>
```

Comment: create image directly from the temp file. Replace $a = $tmp and also replace imagejpeg($thumb, $a, 100); with imagejpeg($thumb, $upload_dir/$names, 100); and remove the line $res=$moveR=move_uploaded_file($tmp, "$upload_dir/$names");